# How to load single css file in webpack instead of multiple files from node_modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack

This is working code but it's loaded all .css file from node_modules
`module: {
    rules: [
          {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  }`

I want load only one css file form node modules that is require in one of .js file?

i.e. file path : node_modules\package_name\dist\style\123.css.

Comment: Hello, Could you please be clearer as to what you need? The title is different from what you explain in the content of your question.
Also, this is what you need: `exclude: /node_modules/`not with the brackets

Comment: Hello Nilesh, I believe my answer won't satisfy your question due to lack of context. But you can simply `import style from  'package/dist/style.css'` or  '../node_modules/your-package/your-style-path.css'. Please provide us some context

Comment: exclude: /node_modules/ it's for .js files not for css files.

Answer (score 0):

Add in an exclude statement to your rule for the `node_modules` folder

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ["css-loader"],
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        }
    ]
}
```